# directory structure for cloudbees app

Tags: cloudbees

we're looking to port our groovy wrapper tool called caelyf onto cloudbees. it is a groovy-based solution so needs a jvm. our sample template directory structure looks like this : https://github.com/caelyf/caelyf/tree/master/template-project  but i am not too familiar with which choice to make from cloudbees frameworks or whether to brew our own clickStack ?

any suggestions greatly appreciated.
thx

Answer (score 1):

you should join cloudbees-dev@googlegroups.com to discuss this directly with cloudbees engineering.

The main question is to know how to run the application from a simple JVM. Then you can either use the [Java Stack](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container), or maybe will want to setup a custom stack to include framework runtime and let user only provide application classes as a ZIP